# MVC returning entity with foreign key

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

New to MVC and pretty much working my backwards through an application.  I have an entity, ItemType, that has a foreign key to the ItemIndicator class.  Basically I'm creating an editable grid that has the ItemType.code and the ItemIndicator.description in it.  When the user clicks the grid, the ItemIndicator field displays a dropDownList of possible ItemIndicator.descriptions.  In my repository, we have a task that returns an async task of the types as follows:

```
        public async Task<PagedResults<ItemType>> GetAsync(int indId, int skip = 0, int take = -1)
    {
        PagedResults<ItemType> pagedResults;
        try
        {
            IQueryable<ChargeType> query = _dbSet.Include("IndicatorDetails");

            query = take == -1
                ? query.OrderBy(i => i.IndicatorDetails.Code)
                : query.OrderBy(i => i.IndicatorDetails.Code);

            var data = await query.ToListAsync();

            pagedResults = new PagedResults<ItemType>(data, skip, take, data.Count);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            throw new Exception(string.Format("Could not get charge types from database. {0}", e.Message), e);
        }
        return pagedResults;
    }
```

and it works, plus I actually understand it.  The idea is to include the Indicator details, which includes the indicator description that I need.  My problem is the second task:

```
       public async Task<ItemType> GetByIdAsync(int id)
    {
        return await _dbSet.FirstOrDefaultAsync(i => i.Id == id);
    }
```

So the first task returns all of the item types, with the related description info.  What I need the second task to do is pretty much the same thing, I just need the one ItemType with it's associated description info.  Since I'm not expecting more than one result, should just return the one row, I'm confused as to how to rework the expression to return the ItemDescription when the id is passed in.  I get that it works in the PagedResults task because it's of type IQueryable, just not sure how to do that for a single row.

Sorry if this seems kind of scattered, learning the whole framework at once.  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to just use `.Include` and entity will make the correct connection between `ItemType` and `IndicatorDetails`

```
public async Task<ItemType> GetByIdAsync(int id)
{
    return await _dbSet.Include("IndicatorDetails").FirstOrDefaultAsync(i => i.Id == id);
}
```

Comment: Man, so simple.  Thank you so much Michael!

Comment: Any quick fix if I don't have the id?  Just want to return all rows but can't figure out how to relate the two from inside the repository

Comment: `_dbSet.Include("IndicatorDetails").ToList()`

Comment: No luck, the IndicatorDetails comes back null.

Comment: It returns `null` for all of them?

Comment: Yes.  I can see why it works when the ID is passed in, because that would be a relation between the classes.  ItemType comes back, but the indicatorDetails is null.

Comment: The relation is in entity. I don't see how the `FirstOrDefault` would work and `ToList` wouldn't. I'm thinking you've got something else going on. Maybe update your question with the new issue?

Comment: Actually added a new question:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30759723/mvc-returning-entity-with-foreign-key-again/30760911?noredirect=1#comment49575594_30760911