# MVC returning entity with foreign key, again

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I'm trying to return an entity that has a foreign key and I'm a bit stuck.  Trying to populate a dropDownList with the results of two tables.  There's a foreign key relationship between the ItemType and IndicatorType tables.

Code is:

```
public async Task<PagedResults<ItemType>> GetAsync(int skip = 0, int take = -1)
{
    PagedResults<ItemType> pagedResults;
    try
    {
        IQueryable<ItemType> query = _dbSet.Include("IndicatorDetails");
            query = take == -1
            ? query.OrderBy(i => i.IndicatorDetails.Code)
            : query.OrderBy(i => i.IndicatorDetails.Code);
            var data = await query.ToListAsync();

            pagedResults = new PagedResults<ItemType>(data, skip, take, data.Count);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        throw new Exception(string.Format("Could not get item types from database. {0}", e.Message), e);
    }
    return pagedResults;
}
```

I can get it to work for just returning a single row, because I'm passing in an id that I can match between ItemType and IndicatorType classes but I can't figure out how to get the _dbSet to do the include the IndicatorDetails.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Thanks for the spacing correction.

Answer (score 0):

you can always do the query by joining both table
exemple (**j1** is your **ItemType** and **j2** is your **IndicatorType**)

```
ViewBag.listItems = ItemType.Join(IndicatorType, j1 => j1.key, j2 => j2.key2, (j1, j2) => new {j1, j2}).AsEnumerable().Select( v => new SelectListItem() { Value = t.t1.userid.ToString(), Text = string.Format("{0} {1}", t.t1.firstName, t.t2.lastName) });
```

in view you can pass **ViewBag.listItems**

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.userid, new SelectList(ViewBag.listItems,"Value","Text","-Sélections-"), new { @class ="form-control"})
```

Comment: Really trying to do this in the repository to stay consistent with what I was given.  I got it to work when I'm trying to return a single value, because I'm passing in an ID and can just match that ID up on the child table in the LINQ query, but I can't find any way to relate it otherwise.

Comment: that normal since its a relation 1 on 1 but include doesnt do any relation

Comment: it only tell Entity Framwork that you want to include data from other table so there is no join between them

Comment: maybe this will help you http://blogs.msdn.com/b/alexj/archive/2009/06/02/tip-22-how-to-make-include-really-include.aspx